HDD shows up ub lsblk but not blkid
I'm building a Ubuntu 24.04 server and trying to get the UUIDs of attached HDDs. They show up when running lsblk, but not when running sudo blkid (only my OS NVME shows up). The Ubuntu documentation says I should be able to get the UUID by the blkid command whether it's mounted or not, but unfortunately no go so far. I realize info is scarce, but I honestly don't know what to add. Any ideas?

Why do you need to use blkid? its man page even suggests using lsblk instead. One reason for the difference in output may be that blkid caches results - you can try blkid -c /dev/null to start with an empty cache.

Perhaps I'm searching wrong, but I'm not sure how lsblk is usable to get uuid. I tried running the command you suggested but still, only the NVME shows up as blkid output.

Ah sorry I missed the mention of UUID - while lsblk default output doesn't include UUID it should be an available column. Try lsblk -o+UUID for example. The full list of available output columns can be obtained from lsblk --help.

Unfortunately, while that command shows the UUIDs of some of the NVME partitions I have, it doesn't show a UUID for the HDD (blank).
